# Transform the dynamic output into generic list List<T>

Tags: c#, dynamic, arraylist, ado.net, generic-list

I get query result from SQL Server with dynamic number of columns with variable column names. 
How can I transform the result from datareader into generic list List ?

```
 public ? getItems(string orderId)
    {

        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conn);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            command.Connection = sqlConn;
            command.CommandText = "usp_get_orders";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", orderId)));

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                ?
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

        }
        finally
        {

            command.Dispose();
            command1.Dispose();
            sqlConn.Close();
            sqlConn.Dispose();
        }

        return ?;
    }
```

Comment: show us some code, how do you create the reader for example

Comment: how can I return dynamic result with variable number of columns and columns names as list ?

Comment: You can't, really, at least not in a meaningful way.  The best option here is to use something like a `DataTable` instead.

Comment: @Servy of cause you can, and please no `DataTable`, DataTables are crap (slow)

Comment: @Ela They're not *that* slow.  They can be slower than other options because they do a lot for you.  In many contexts you don't need much of what they give you, but this appears to be a context in which the OP really needs some of the generality gained from `DataTable`, so it's likely to actually have comparable performance to another solution.  My guess is it would be [marginally] faster (but dramatically less memory intensive) than your answer, for example, as creating a lot of small dictionaries is expensive, relatively speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you resulting object is completely dynamic you could use a dictionary instead of a strongly typed object. Or, if you want at least an object, go with dynamic objects. Either use the `dynamic` keyword and a `List<dynamic>` or use `DynamicObject`.
The difference to a dictionary is not that big though...

Something like this could do it:

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
var listOfValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
while (reader.Read())
{
   for(int i = 0; i <reader.FieldCount;i++)
   {
      listOfValues.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));
   }
}
```